# Pandas DF to a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe (df) and I want to transform it to a nested list.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Number':[1,2,3,4,5, 6],
             'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
             'Value': [223, 124, 434, 514, 821, 110]})
```

My expected outcome is a nested list. The first list inside the nested takes values from the first 3 rows of df from the first column. The second then the first 3 rows of the second column and the third the 3 first rows of the third column. After that I want to add lists of the remaning 3 rows.

```
[[1, 2, 3], 
 ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
 [223, 124, 434]
 [4, 5, 6], 
['D', 'E', 'F'],
[514, 821, 110]]
```

I did a for loop and called tolist() on each series. Then I get all the values from one column in a list. How do I go from the outcome below to the expected outcome above?

```
col=df.columns

lst=[]
for i in col:
        temp = df[i].tolist()
        temp
        lst.append(temp)
```

Outcome (lst):

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
 [223, 124, 434, 514, 821, 110]]
```

Comment: Something like `df.iloc[:3,:].T.values.tolist() + df.iloc[3:,:].T.values.tolist()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
lst = df.set_index(df.index // 3).groupby(level=0).agg(list) \
        .to_numpy().ravel().tolist()
print(lst)

# Output
[[1, 2, 3],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 [223, 124, 434],
 [4, 5, 6],
 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 [514, 821, 110]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `.values` and some numpy slicing

```
v = df.values.T
v[:,:3].tolist() + v[:,3:].tolist()
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 [223, 124, 434],
 [4, 5, 6],
 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 [514, 821, 110]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example starting from 3 lists, the ones you got doing `.tolist()`

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4]
b = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
c = [223, 124, 434, 514, 821, 110]

res = []

for i in range(len(a) // 3):
  res.append(a[i * 3:(i * 3) + 3])
  res.append(b[i * 3:(i * 3) + 3])
  res.append(c[i * 3:(i * 3) + 3])
```

result is

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], [223, 124, 434], [4, 5, 6], ['D', 'E', 'F'], [514, 821, 110]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Number':[1,2,3,4,5, 6],
    'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'Value': [223, 124, 434, 514, 821, 110]
})

# convert df into slices of 3

final_list = []
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
    final_list.append(
        df.iloc[i:i+3]['Number'].to_list())
    final_list.append(
        df.iloc[i:i+3]['Name'].to_list())
    final_list.append(
        df.iloc[i:i+3]['Value'].to_list())
    

print(final_list)
```

output

```
[[1, 2, 3], ['A', 'B', 'C'], [223, 124, 434], [4, 5, 6], ['D', 'E', 'F'], [514, 821, 110]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to divide the list (column) into list of size n.
You can change the value of n, to change the sublist size.

```
lst=[]
n=3
for i in col:
        temp = df[i].tolist()
        for i in range(0,len(temp),n):
            lst.append(temp[i:i+n])
```